# How to hold the true value of many checkboxes at once after page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The search is working fine.but my problem is When i checked one checkbox and searched,It will get my results and also checkbox true state also exist after the refresh.But when checking two or more checkboxes it doesn't hold the true states.I need to hold those true states

My problem is i have 4 checkboxes. when i checkd two or more checkboxes at once, it will get my results and then true states are gone.I need to hold these states to print the report after the page refresh.

This is my current view of four checkboxes.

```
.row
 .col-md-3
 = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]","CUS", params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] == 'CUS'
 = label_tag "Organizational Customer"
 .col-md-3
 = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]", "SUP",  params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] == 'SUP'
 = label_tag "Organzational Supplier"
 col-md-3
 = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]", "INDCUS", params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] == 'INDCUS'
 = label_tag "Individual Customer"
 .col-md-3
 = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]", "INDSUP",  params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] == 'INDSUP'
 = label_tag "Individual Supplier"
```

This is my controller

```
 def customer_supplier_report
    Organization
    Address
    ContactNumber
    refined_query = ""
    if params[:search].present? or params[:excel_report].present?

      search_customer_supplier = params[:search_customer_supplier]
      if params[:organization_children].present? and search_customer_supplier["id"].present?
        organization_id = search_customer_supplier["id"]
        organization = Organization.find(organization_id)
        anchestor_ids = organization.anchestors.map{|o| o[:member].id }
        search_customer_supplier["id"] = "(#{anchestor_ids.join(' OR ')})" if anchestor_ids.any?
        end

      #puts "======================================================================"
      # puts params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code']

      params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] = params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].join(" OR ") if params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].present?

      puts params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code']

      customer_report = params[:search_customer_supplier].map { |k, v| "#{k}:#{v}" if v.present? }.compact


    else
      customer_report = ["accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code:(CUS OR SUP OR INDCUS OR INDSUP)"]
    end

    @all_address = params[:all_address].to_bool if params[:all_address].present?
    refined_query += customer_report.join(" AND ")
    params[:query] = refined_query
    params[:per_page] = 4000
    @customer_reports = Organization.search(params)



    @account_managers = User.where(active: true)
    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:excel_report].present?
        request.format = "xls"
        format.xls { set_attachment_name "customer_supplier_report.xls" }
      else
        format.html
      end
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field name `search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]` means that `params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code']` is an array, so you should check it for inclusion:

```
check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]",
  "CUS",
  params.dig(:search_customer_supplier, 'accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code')&.include?('CUS')
```

Comment: It gives me error..
`undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @AnujaDx try `&.include?` (requires ruby >= 2.3)

Comment: It works,but i have to add params.dig method instead params[].Thanks a lot

Comment: I have a similar problem,I will attach the link of the question here.It's great if  i can get help from u.
[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244947/hold-both-params-of-decendant-checkbox-accociate-with-parent-input-field ]