# Hold both params of Decendant checkbox accociate with parent input_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a `select_tag` to select the customer. When user selected a customer, it will generate a child checkbox_from below the `select_tag`.

User can select a customer and check the decendant checkbox both or either only customer.

If user select only a customer then searched,It will get the results and `select_tag` value(param) also hold in the select tag after the refresh.

But the problem is if I try get the both `select_tag` and `checkbox_tag` data, it will generate the data but both params are gone. I need to hold both params after the search results.

This is my view

```
.row
            .col-md-3
              = label_tag "Customer/Supplier Name"
              = select_tag "search_customer_supplier[id]", options_from_collection_for_select(Organization.customers_and_suppliers, :id, :name, params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'id')), class: "form-control parent_class chosen-select", id: "search_registered_customers", include_blank: true
              .col-md-10.small_scale_margin-top2#check_children_wrapper.hide
                = label_tag "Descendent"
                = check_box_tag "organization_children", "true", params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'organization_children')&.include?('true')
```

This is my controller code regarding to the checkbox

```
def customer_supplier_report
    Organization
    Address
    ContactNumber
    refined_query = ""
    if params[:search].present? or params[:excel_report].present?

      search_customer_supplier = params[:search_customer_supplier]
      if params[:organization_children].present? and search_customer_supplier["id"].present?
        organization_id = search_customer_supplier["id"]
        organization = Organization.find(organization_id)
        anchestor_ids = organization.anchestors.map{|o| o[:member].id }
        search_customer_supplier["id"] = "(#{anchestor_ids.join(' OR ')})" if anchestor_ids.any?
        end

      params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] = params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].join(" OR ") if params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].present?

      customer_report = params[:search_customer_supplier].map { |k, v| "#{k}:#{v}" if v.present? }.compact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the opposite of your previous question.

Your `check_box_tag`'s parameter name is `'organization_children'`, so it will be passed in `params[:organization_children]`. You access it correctly in controller, do the same in the view:

```
= check_box_tag "organization_children", "true", params[:organization_children].present?
```

Comment: I check this method also,But it hold only the checkbox param.The other select box param goes after the search.

Comment: @AnujaDx that may be because id in params is a string and id is integer, try `params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'id').to_i`